# Two same Jquery code but only one is working in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have copied a code from jQuery site to show images as a slider (.Rondell) 
in SharePoint 2013 I created 2 Content Web Part Editor and called the .js file that has the code in it.

When the page is refreshed only 1 of them is executed and working fine. the 2 of them never works. Even though they are exactly the same code the only difference is the path of the images.

Below is my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../SiteAssets/jquery.rondell.css" type="text/css" media="all" title="Screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/jquery.rondell.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="rondellSlider">
  <img src="../SiteAssets/images/hussam3.jpg" alt="houssam" title="Houssam Adel">
  <img src="../SiteAssets/images/hana2.jpg" alt="hana" title="Hana Al Mazrooa">
  <img src="../SiteAssets/images/sally2.jpg" alt="sally" title="Sally Gazzaz">
  <img src="../SiteAssets/images/usman2.jpg" alt="usman" title="Usman Mahmood">
  <img src="../SiteAssets/images/joseph2.jpg" alt="joseph" title="Joseph Sosa">
  <img src="../SiteAssets/images/yousef2.jpg" alt="sally" title="Yousef Abuown">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" >
  $(function() {
    $('#rondellSlider').rondell({
      preset: 'slider'
    });
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you have any error in your web browser ? Could help to explain why the second Web Part don't work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have two divs that use the `rondellSlider` ID, and that you make this call twice:

```
$('#rondellSlider').rondell({
    preset: 'slider'
});
```

If that is the case, it would be normal for just one of them to become a slide as IDs are supposed to be unique. Try giving the second container div another ID and use that ID when you call the slider on your second content editor webpart.